# Toggle inside onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to work out how I can put a toggle inside an onclick of an img tag.

i.e.

```
<img src="..." onclick="IWANTITHERE" />
```

**not using an event handler like so...**

```
$('img').toggle(function()
    {$(this).animate({width: '400px'}, 'slow');},
    function()
    {$(this).animate({width: '120px'}, 'slow');
});
```

The following has some funky side effects like performing the animation over and over from one mouse click...

```
<img src="..." onclick="$(this).toggle(function()
    {$(this).animate({width: '400px'}, 'slow');},
    function()
    {$(this).animate({width: '120px'}, 'slow');
});" />
```

**UPDATE**: The problem I have with using non-inline functions is that the site is mahusive (about 1.5 million lines of code) and uses shedloads of scripts and calls... it's a real mess... and because of the mess function calls won't work in my invoked control which is inside an updatepanel :( which is why I want an inline script. I also need to toggle the image larger / smaller... not just make it larger.

**UPDATE2**: I'm currently resorting to using basic onmouse events in the img tag... but of course this is only a toggle with mouse interaction...

```
<img src='...' onmouseover="$(this).animate({width: '400px', height: '400px'}, 'slow');" onmouseout="$(this).animate({width: '120px', height: '120px'}, 'slow');">;
```

Comment: Don't use inline function and `.toggle(fn, fn)` is  deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: good point... but how can I perform 'toggle' like functionality with inline jquery/javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, I assume what you want is to perform a resize animation when onclick event is fired. If that is the case I recommend:

```
//html
<img id="id" src="..."/>

//js
<script>
      $('#id').on('click', function (){
          $(this).addClass('resize');
      })
</script>

//css
.resize{
    -moz-animation: risezeFunction 0.8s alternate infinite ease 0s;
}

@-moz-keyframes risezeFunction {
    to {
        width: 400px;
    }
    from {
        width: 120px;
    }
}
```

Of course you have to use the **keyframes** variant that suits your browser(**@-webkit-keyframes**, **@-ms-keyframes**, **@-webkit-keyframes**, etc), or all of them would be the best.

Again, this is assuming THIS is what you want to achieve, if not, please elaborate a little bit more on your actual goal. Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Based on your last comment:

```
onclick="
if($(this).css('width') === '400px'){
    $(this).animate({
    width: '120px'}, 'slow');
}
else {
    $(this).animate({
    width: '400px'}, 'slow');
}"
```

This is a little "stiff" but maybe it'll serve as a base for a more elaborate solution, hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I have with using non-inline functions is that the site is mahusive (about 1.5 million lines of code) and uses shedloads of scripts and calls... it's a real mess... and because of the mess function calls won't work in my invoked control which is inside an updatepanel :( which is why I want an inline script. I also need to toggle the image larger / smaller... not just make it larger.

Comment: please explain me if what you want is the image to toggle large/small infinitely when clicked OR just to get larger when clicked and small when clicked again OR what you just said last about onmouseover events...

Comment: e.g. on first click it will get bigger, on second click it will go back to normal size (120px)